# recommend a good tutorial about Silverlight animation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, animation

Could anyone recommend me a good tutorial about Silverlight animation for a beginner, and I am especially interested in how to read the animation code in XAML (I always feel magic code) and develop my own animation. If the tutorial covers any tools which could facilitate animation code rede and animation development, it will be great!

Thanks in advance,

George

Comment: How strange, while looking at this question there was an advert to the right 'Learn Silverlight Today!'... http://silverlight-tour.com/?stackoverflow. Was this a pure coincidence or some clever advertising!?

Answer (score 1):

I found to be the best starting point is actually the silverlight.net page.

[Silverlight.net / Learning](http://silverlight.net/Learn/)

delivers a lot of quite well made tutorial videos. Animations inclusive! :)

Comment: Thanks, any printable readable documents? I feel it is more impressive for me to read some printable documents, videos are hard to take notes. :-)

Comment: I really love Tim Heuer Blog 
http://timheuer.com/blog/Tags/silverlight/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You might want to download the Microsoft Expression Blend trial. Blend makes it easier to develop applications for both WPF and Silverlight. The startup screen contains some examples.

And this site is pretty useful:
http://silverlight.net/quickstarts/

Comment: Sorry, I am targetting Silverlight 2, not 3. Any recommendations for Silverlight 2?

Comment: Use expression studio V2 (although v3 might support Silverlight 2 as well). Here's the link:
http://www.microsoft.com/expression/try-it/try-it-v2.aspx

Comment: These tutorials are in text:
http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials.aspx

Comment: I think you mean using Expression Blend? Is there a tutorial for Expression Blend with Silverlight? I am new to Expression Blend.

Comment: There is no animation related tutorials from the above link you recommended. Any more recommendations? :-)

Comment: Expression Blend contains an example project in the StartUp page of the program. For more on animation read this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189090(VS.95).aspx and perhaps this one: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/02/28/first-look-at-using-expression-blend-with-silverlight-2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

On [Microsoft Showcase](http://www.microsoft.com/video/en/us/search?phrase=silverlight) there are a lot of great video tutorial about Silverlight and Expression Blend.

In your case I would recomend watching [Silverlight Fundamentals (Part 7 of 9): Animation](http://www.microsoft.com/video/en/us/details/9b002e70-78c2-4741-9093-93e42228d8d1).

Answer (score 0):

The Project Rosetta at http://channel9.msdn.com/continuum/tutorials can be helpful

> *The Project "Rosetta Stone" Tutorials are dedicated to helping designers and developers build applications in Silverlight while taking advantage of skills they already know.*